# How do I make a link open the linked page's video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, hyperlink

Long story short: (tried looking this up to no avail; maybe not wording it right? newbie here).

I'm working on a mobile-friendly webpage. On this webpage is a button. When you click said button, it takes you to ANOTHER webpage with a video on it.

The desired effect I'm looking for is when you click on the button, it doesn't take you to the new page, but rather opens up the video on the spot.

Is this achievable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the code below what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a jsfiddle, see below, so that if you click on the button, it loads the video without bringing you to a new page as you requested.

http://jsfiddle.net/yb6s7fud/

Here is the jquery code I used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var video = '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/koJlIGDImiU?autoplay=1" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
            $("#video").append(video);
        });
    });
```

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: It still opens the other webpage sir.

Comment: @Herpy_McDOOPSTAH how do you mean? it is still the same page -- check the jsfiddle again, I updated it, might be clearer now, also hope you like enrique inglesisas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With youtube you can easily open the video in a modal box.

With other webiste you can open a iframe modal with the entire page content. You can affect iframe with jquery to take only the video only if the other page is the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a container with the right properties so inside you can place an iframe? The button should be the anchor to the iframe source.